# get controller name & action in view file in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to get controller and action name in respective view file

as when I GOTO login page

```
Controller=> authenticate   
And action=> Login
```

come in action

I want to get those name directly in view with out passing it from each and every controller, because on every view file I want controller and action name.

Comment: Why don't you save them into variables inside your controller and use them in the view?

Answer (score 2):

To do this the proper ZF2 way you should write a custom view helper.

You can call this view helper for example `RouteMatchHelper`.

Then in the view you can simply do `$this->routeMatchHelper();`

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class RouteMatchHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
      * @var RouteMatch
      */
    protected $routeMatch;

    /**
     * Constructor with dependency
     *
     * @param RouteMatch $routeMatch
     */
    public function __construct(RouteMatch $routeMatch)
    {
        $this->routeMatch = $routeMatch;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $controller = $this->routeMatch->getParam('controller');
        $action = $this->routeMatch->getParam('action');
        return sprintf(
            "the action is %s and the controller name is %s",
            $action,
            $controller
        );
    }
}
```

You need `RouteMatch` in your view helper so you have to setup a factory. You will have to register the factory under the `view_helpers` key in your `module.config.php` file:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'routeMatchHelper' => `Application\View\Helper\RouteMatchHelperFactory`
    )
)
```

And then the factory itself:

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class RouteMatchHelperFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return RouteMatchHelper
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        /** @var RouteMatch $routeMatch */
        $routeMatch = $serviceManager->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
        return new RouteMatchHelper($routeMatch);
    }
}
```

This code is not tested, but you get the point.
You can read more on writeing custom helperss [in the official ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html#writing-custom-helpers).